# how to simulate wide swing cascode current mirror

Tags: design, current-mirror

I want to design a wide swing cascode current mirror (question-left) and in order to apply Iref, I have designed a PTAT and applied it to M3 and M5. Iref must be 50uA and the diagram of output should be like the diagram in picture (question-right).
The problem is that, When I do simulation, I have I=0 for V<0.6 and it gradually increases, while it shouldn't be like this. I don't know in which part I'm designing wrong and I don't know how to solve it. would you please help me urgently????
Thanks in advance.[image: question]

The other image is the result of my designed circuit.
[image: result]

Comment: I assume you mean I0=0 for V_M3D<0.6. That shouldn't be all that surprising as the threshold voltage of a mosfet is about 0.6 or 0.7. M1/M2 just won't conduct much at anything below that voltage. You should add in a plot of your simulation results though so we can help troubleshoot what happens in the region where V>0.6.

Comment: If you can include W/L for the different transistors that might help. The green curve looks like it shows short channel effects.

Comment: I selected the W/L of transistors based on calculations. still didn't work.